# How to see if method is used anywhere?

Tags: apex

I am working on cleaning and refactoring our current solution. I wonder there is possibility how to find out if and where is single method used in the code? For example VisualStudio's Intellisense shows references of methods, properties etc. Is something that available for apex?

Comment: Open developer console and then hit *(cmd + shift + h)* and search for the method name here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apex doesn't have tooling available to do this in a really nice, pervasive way. There's two basic approaches that I'm aware of.

- Pull down all the source (classes *and* triggers) into your favorite IDE, and perform a global search. You can do this in Eclipse, Visual Studio Code, Sublime + MavensMate, or whatever you prefer.
- There's an approach using the Tooling API that Andrew Fawcett [wrote up](https://andyinthecloud.com/2013/02/02/spring-cleaning-apex-code-with-the-tooling-api/) several years ago as a rudimentary dead-code detector. While his [implementation](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-codeanalysis) has not been updated in some years, the approach is still valid.

Note that both of these approaches can miss some ways in which a method can be used outside of Apex-to-Apex references, so you need to be aware of `@InvocableMethod`, Visualforce action methods, and so on.